# probability that the stock price is below the strike price

Tags: probability, risk-neutral-measure

How can I prove that under the risk-neutral probability:

$\mathbb{P}[S_{t}<K]=-\frac{\partial{C}}{\partial{K}}(K,T)$

where

$S_{t}$ is the stock price, K is the strike price, C is the call option price

Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your posting has an error, that is, the identity should be
\begin{align*}
-P(0, T) \mathbb{P}(S_T > K) = \frac{\partial C}{\partial K}.
\end{align*}
The derivation below is based on this assumption.
We denote by $f(x)$ the density function for $S_T$. Then
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(S_T > K) = \int_K^{\infty} f(x) dx,
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
C(K, T) &= P(0, T) \mathbb{E}\big((S_T-K)^+ \big)\\
&=P(0, T) \int_K^{\infty}(x-K) f(x) dx\\
&= P(0, T)\bigg[\int_K^{\infty} x f(x) dx - K \int_K^{\infty}f(x) dx \bigg].
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial C}{\partial K} = -P(0, T)\int_K^{\infty} f(x) dx.
\end{align*}
That is,
\begin{align*}
-P(0, T) \mathbb{P}(S_T > K) = \frac{\partial C}{\partial K}.
\end{align*}

We can additionally obtain that
\begin{align*}
P(0, T) f(K) = \frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial K^2}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Okay thank you very much . Now I understand where this formula comes from. In my formula, it was supposed that r = 0 that's why there is not the term P(0,T) but I think there is no effect about the false formula I wrote ...

Comment: Just an interrogation: $\mathbb{E}[(S_{T}-K)+]P(0,T)=C(K,T)$ is this a formula that we can prove or is this the definition of the price of the option ?

Comment: @glork: The formula $\mathbb{E}[(S_T-K)^+]P(0, T) = C(K, T)$ is obtained by assuming deterministic interest rates, or by treating $\mathbb{E}$ as the expectation operator under the $T$-forward measure.