# Bimodal option pricing based on P.D.F

Tags: options, option-pricing

is there any literature on option pricing given the pdf of the underlying asset - e.g. i am interested in seeing how prices for a range of strikes ought to compare based on, say, a simple normal distribution vs. a bi-modal(mixture of 2 normals) vs. a log-normal distribution. python-based solutions would work as well

Comment: My answers to https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/31368 and https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/30749 might be useful.

Comment: very helpful! how do you translate the implied density to implied vols in the first chart of your first link?

Comment: I replied by commenting on that answer.

Comment: user38537, did you find a answer to your question ?
I am very interested in finding a paper with this particular subject. Tks