# Alternative Method for Determining Option-Implied pdf

Tags: options, implied-volatility, distribution, pdf, cdf

As I am refining a pricing model to incorporate skew, and not just ATM volatilities, I need to create random realizations of the underlying consistent with the skew-implied pdf. When searching, one ends up with the Breeden-Litzenberger formula, which states that:

$\frac{\partial^{2}C}{\partial K^{2}}=e^{-rT}g(S_{T})$

As I am slightly wary of using numerical second derivatives in my code, I looked for an alternative way of obtaining this. I came up with the idea of using correctly skew-adjusted cash-or-nothing binary put prices in order to derive the CDF of the underlying:

$P_{dig}=P_{dig,noskew}+\nu_{vanilla}*\frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial K}$

As $CDF=e^{rT}P_{dig}$, I run [0,1]-normally distributed random numbers through the inverse function $CDF^{-1}$ to get realizations of the underlying that are distributed consistent with the skew.

**Can I please have your views on this / please comment if I am missing something here**

Comment: If all you want is the CDF and not the PDF, then you could also use $\partial C / \partial K$ instead of the second order derivative. You might also find my answer to https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/30749 helpful.

Comment: So basically that would be $1+\partial C/\partial K$

Comment: Yes - but don't forget to multiply the derivative by the discount factor.

Comment: Coded this up now as proposed by you, works like a charm. For anyone who wants to try - you need to compute the CDF over a quite wide range of values in order not to truncate the pdf that is implicit in the distribution of underlying values.

Comment: @zrh if you have some analytic form for the smile, then you can compute the second derivative numerically to arbitrary precision - what is your worry?